# Evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^{18}\sin{\left(\frac{(2n+1)^2\pi}{38}\right)}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{18}\sin{\left(\frac{(2n)^2\pi}{38}\right)}$

Tags: trigonometry, summation

How to show that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{18}\sin{\left(\frac{(2n+1)^2\pi}{38}\right)}=\sum_{n=0}^{18}\sin{\left(\frac{(2n+1)^4\pi}{38}\right)}=\sum_{n=0}^{18}\sin{\left(\frac{(2n+1)^8\pi}{38}\right)}=0$$

and
$$\sum_{n=0}^{18}\sin{\left(\frac{(2n)^2\pi}{38}\right)}=\sum_{n=0}^{18}\sin{\left(\frac{(2n)^4\pi}{38}\right)}=\sum_{n=0}^{18}\sin{\left(\frac{(2n)^8\pi}{38}\right)}=\sqrt{19}$$